# Windows Forms: Change application mainwindow at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mainwindow

Normally I would do Application.Run(myMainForm).

But I want to do something like this:

```
MyForm1 f = new MyForm1();
f.Close+=OnOpenOverviewWin();
Application.Run(f);

void OnOpenOverviewWin()
{
MyOverViewForm f = new MyOverViewForm ();
Application.Run(f); // i want to do this
Application.NewMainWindow = f; // or something like that
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [Application.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) property to [ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode.aspx)

```
MyForm1 f = new MyForm1();
f.Close += OnOpenOverviewWin();
Application.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
Application.Run(f);

void OnOpenOverviewWin()
{
  MyOverViewForm f = new MyOverViewForm ();
  f.Show();
}
```

Comment: has the mainwindow no other implications than that the app is closed?

Comment: The MainWindow property will get changed if you close the first window opened.  You can also set the MainWindow to your new window in your close handler rather than changing the ShutdownMode.

Comment: Which MainWindow property? The Application class doesn't have such a thing.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong Application class.  You're right, there is no MainWindow property.  That property was added in the WPF version of the Application class, so you'll have to change the ShutdownMode.

Comment: The ShutdownMode property also is defined on the WPF-Application class only.