# Dispose main form and create new one c#

Tags: c#, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Forms: Change application mainwindow at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028843/windows-forms-change-application-mainwindow-at-runtime)

I want to create new form, and destroy main form in c#.
How i can do this?

```
var fw2 = new Form2();
fw2.Show();
this.Dispose();
```

This code just show second form for a one second and close my program.
Any ideas?

Comment: The main message pump is attached to the first form, most likely, so closing it closes the pump, which then goes on to exit `Main` - closing the primary thread. Instead of closing the first form, a quick option would be to `Hide` it.

Comment: Ok, i can use this.Hide() instead this.Dispose() then it works. But i have to call Enviorment.Exit(0), when user want to Close second form.

Comment: You could have the first form subscribe to the second forms `Closed` event, and on `Closed` close form 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this sort of thing in the Program class. I just put the below code normally seen in the Main method into a loop.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new frmMain());
```

Once the main form has closed the code leaves the 'Run' method and goes into a loop which checks a application global variable to see if it needs to render a new form.

This is over kill if you just want to open a new form but it seems to work quite well if you are regularly 'swapping' your main form in and out.

My code looks (a little) like this...

```
while (true)
{
    if (AppSettings.SomeFormSettng = FormSetting.ShowAnotherForm)
    {
        Form showThisForm = AppSettngs.TheForm;
        if (ThisIsTheFirstRun)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            ThisIsTheFirstRun = false;
        }
        Application.Run(new showThisForm ());
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```