# Opening Form2 on Click of button in Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application where, When i click a button on Form1 opens Form2. I have a aone more button on Form2 when i click that it suppose to open Form1.

```
Form 1 :
     Form form2 = new Form2();
     form2 .ShowDialog();
     Form1.Close();
Form 2 : 

     Form form1 = new Form1();
     form1.ShowDialog();
     form2.Close();
```

The Application ends..Can anyone explain how to achieve rectify this?

Comment: "The application ends" when? closing the parent form will cause the program to end since there isn't any form left for it to work with

Comment: sorry that is this.Close();

Comment: The application ends when i Click on the button in the Form2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Form1.Close()` is a typo: You can not close the parent form of an application. Once this window closes, the application closes.

With WPF you could do otherwise:

```
Application.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
```

See: [Windows Forms: Change application mainwindow at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028843/windows-forms-change-application-mainwindow-at-runtime)